# why does the if statement doesn't work properly

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
    public void nextButton()
    {
        if (lvlLoadScript.LoadedLvlNum == 0)
        {
            nextButtonTutorial();
        }
        if (lvlLoadScript.LoadedLvlNum == 1)
        {
            nextButton1();
        }
        if (lvlLoadScript.LoadedLvlNum == 2)
        {
            nextButton2();
        }
    }
```

for some reason this only loads nextButton2() no matter what the LoadedLvlNum is.
(LoadedLvlNum is an int and the nextButtonTutorial-2 void works)

Comment: The information about your problem is too little to understand the situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Debug.Log to see the value of `lvlLoadScript.LoadedLvlNum` to make sure you're setting the correct value. Also if you don't use `If else` the code go through all the if statements in order which can cause unexpected behavior if you're setting the value of `lvlLoadScript.LoadedLvlNum` to 1 or 2 in methods `nextButtonTutorial`, `nextButton1`.

```cs
public void nextButton()
{
    Debug.Log("LoadedLvlNum: " + lvlLoadScript.LoadedLvlNum);
    if (lvlLoadScript.LoadedLvlNum == 0)
    {
        nextButtonTutorial();
    }
    else if (lvlLoadScript.LoadedLvlNum == 1)
    {
        nextButton1();
    }
    else if (lvlLoadScript.LoadedLvlNum == 2)
    {
        nextButton2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use switch case

```
switch (lvlLoadScript.LoadedLvlNum)
  {
     case 0:
        nextButtonTutorial();
        break;
     case 1:
        nextButton1();
        break;
     case 2:
        nextButton2();
        break;
  }
```